# how to config Kestrel Concurrent Number more than 256

Tags: .net-core, kestrel

Now, I was make 1000 websocket connections , and the server is dotnet core 2.x,

but , when I connected 256 webosket instance , the other cannot connect dotnet

core server .

Who can tell me how to config this, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

**MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections**

```
    .UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
    options.Limits.MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections = 100;
});
```